# Python If Variable in Variable

Tags: python, file, filereader

I Have Made A File Called `helloworld.simon`.
In There I  Have Written:

```
Public class helloworld {
main = (main.method());
main {
    console.print("Hello World");
    }
```

And I Have Written This Code:

```
Public = ("Public")
Private = ("Private")
code = open('helloworld.simon' , 'r')
print(code.read())
if Public in code:
    print("Pub")
else:
    print("J")
```

And The *Output* Is:

```
Public class helloworld {
main = (main.method());
main {
    console.print("Hello World");
    }

J
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It printed `J` that's the problem silly! lol

Comment: Hint: `in` should be used on string objects, not file objects.

Comment: @Kevin But How Do I Convert File Object To String Object?

Answer (score 1):

File reading is sequential. Once you read a file (with `print(code.read())` you cant read back again, unless restart reading with `code.seek(0)`

```
Public = ("Public")
Private = ("Private")
code = open('helloworld.simon' , 'r')
print(code.read())
code.seek(0)
if Public in code.read():
    print("Pub")
else:
    print("J")
code.close()
```

outputs:

```
Pub
```

If you comment `code.seek(0)`, outputs J

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`code = open('helloworld.simon' , 'r')`

To this:

```
with open('helloworld.simon' , 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   if any([line for line in lines if Public in line]):
      print("Pub")
   else:
      print("J")
```

Comment: This still prints "J", doesn't it? `"Public" in ["Public class helloworld {\n" , ...]` still evaluates to False.

Comment: @Kevin this doesn't print "J"

Comment: Strange, it prints "J" on my machine. (incidentally, I'm not the one that downvoted)

Comment: @Kevin Hmm... I should specify that I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: 3.5, for me. What do you see if you do `print(lines)`? I get `['Public class helloworld {\n', 'main = (main.method());\n', 'main {\n', '    console.print("Hello World");\n', '    }']`.

Comment: @Kevin you were right, I was doing something incorrectly.  I fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124342/discussion-between-kevin-and-free-mind).